# Convince typescript that object has key from Object.entries/Object.keys

Tags: typescript

```
function thing(foo: FooType): void {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(foo)) {
     // Typescript complains about foo[key]
     foo[key] = <some value>
  }
}
```

Is there any way to convince Typescript that the object `foo` has the key with the value of `key`? It clearly does because I am using `Object.entries`, to iterate over the keys and values of the object, but I can't convince Typescript of this fact.

Comment: Use a type assertion? Though, it'd be more elegant to create a new object instead of writing over an existing one

Comment: isn't const can be replaced with let

Comment: As suggested, I'd just use a type assertion here: `foo[key as keyof foo] = "bar"`. It's doubtful that `Object.entries` will ever be changed to return something other than `string` for the key type. See [this github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208).

Comment: @CRice The `keyof` type assertion isn't working. It tells me I need an index signature (which makes sense), but unfortunate the type `FooType` has no index signatures.

Comment: My mistake, it should be either `foo[key as keyof FooType]` or `foo[key as keyof typeof foo]`.

Comment: You can add this at global scope somewhere `interface ObjectConstructor {
    entries<T>(o: T): [keyof T, any][];
  }` but it may provide misleading results especially for optional properties